# What is the difference between these ways of getting current directory?

Tags: c#

They all give the same result, the location of folder that contains the exe that is being executed.  I am sure there are no good or bad methods in the .net BCL. They are all appropriate in particular circumstances. Which one is appropriate for which scenario?

```
var appBaseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
var currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: If you set a shortcut to the app and specify a "Start in" folder different from the .exe location, GetExecutingAssembly.Location() will be different from CurrentDirectory.  You may also need to consider differences between a standalone app vs running under IIS.

Comment: Duuude... You saved me a tons of time by having asked this question. I know about the differences but never know which is which. And you asking that, helped me not be forced to try them all out. Thanks, mate! Want some bounty?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> They all give the same result

They certainly don’t. `currentDir` and `dir` both give you the *current working directory* – i.e. by default the directory your executable was run *from* (but it can be changed during the execution).

By contrast, `appBaseDir` and `path` get the directory which contains the executing assembly’s file.

To illustrate how they differ, consider that you have an executable which sits in `C:\bar\baz.exe`. Now I can execute the application by entering the following chain of commands in a terminal:

```
$ md C:\foo
$ cd C:\foo
$ ..\bar\baz.exe
```

Now the current working directory is `C:\foo` but the application’s base directory is `C:\bar`. There exist analogous means of setting the working directory for other methods of launching an application (e.g. via a shortcut icon or programmatically, such as via `Process.Start`).

Still, the framework provides different ways of accessing this information:

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` quite directly conveys the meaning that the execution environment (an environment variable) is queried. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` *may* actually do the same internally (I have no idea) but it encapsulates this, and rather focuses on providing the user with a logical API for querying information about directories.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain` has information about the current `AppDomain` (roughly, the executable). Part of that information is, logically, the `AppDomain`’s path. By contrast, `System.Reflection.Assembly` gives you general information about *assembles* – these represent any kind of binary objects in .NET, including DLLs and EXEs. `GetExecutingAssembly` in particular returns the currently executed assembly. And you can get *its* path again by querying its `Location` property, which gives the physical path of an assembly file.

Comment: The current working directory is not the directory the executable was run from. A program can change its own working directory. Downvote not mine by the way. I'm just waiting for you to fix the minor inaccuracy.

Comment: currentDir is not where the executable was run from, if anything has caused Environment's CurrentDirectory to change.

Comment: currentDir can actually change during the execution. If you open an open/save dialog and the user navigates to a different directory, the value of `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` will change to that directory.

Comment: I'm going to continue to quibble. Please do forgive me. What does "run from" actually mean. For example, suppose I start the process by calling `CreateProcess`. What does "run from" mean there. If I pass `NULL` in the working directory parameter, the new process will inherit its parent's working directory. If a specific value is passed, then that is used.

Comment: @David Quibbles are fine. However, don’t you think this exceeds the scope of the answer? But I will mention that there are other ways of specifying the working directory.

Answer (score 30):

[image]

Consider the example above 
The myTest.exe file contains the entry point and is at located at `D:\myTest.exe`. This exe calls via reflection a method in an assembly in `F:\`. This assembly contains all the find directory code.

In the command prompt I have my current directory set to `C:\`

Here are the results

**AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**

```
D:\
```

**Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)**

```
F:\
```

**Environment.CurrentDirectory and Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()**

```
C:\
```

Answer (score 6):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will give you the directory the application is running in.

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` & `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` can change during the execution of an application.  You can see the behavior if you get the value at the start of execution, then use something like `OpenFileDialog`, then then get the value again.  You will notice that the value will have changed to where the OpenFileDialog was pointing.

Answer (score 1):

I found with .net 5 that if the application is published as a self-contained single-file EXE, all of these well-known methods to get the EXE location return an empty string:

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`
`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`
`typeof(Program).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName`

However this does work to get the containing folder path:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`