# C# how do I draw on files in the same location as i'm running the program without a long path

Tags: c#

So far I haven't found anything that would allow my program to access text files that are in the same folder as it.
for example:
if my file is in C:/testingfolder i would need to use C:/testingfolder/filenames.txt to access the other files, the problem with this is sometimes it wont be in c:/testingfolder but instead it might be in E:/importantfiles or F:/backup and it needs to run from all of those.

If anyone could explain or give code that showed how to make a longer path into a "same folder" path that would answer my question.

Comment: If you mean relative to the location of the process .exe [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52797/314291).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` you can get the path of your process that is executing, then you should use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` method to concatenate this path with the name of your file, and you will get the absolute location of your file.

Comment: It might be dangerous to use this method, see: [What is the difference between these ways of getting current directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727692/what-is-the-difference-between-these-ways-of-getting-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `System.IO` and `System.Text`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
```

then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = "";
    // look for the file "myfile.txt" in application root directory
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```