# How can I make shorter imagepath

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm trying to change the imagebox picture when the button is pressed.

```
if (label1.Text=="1")
{
    pictureBox1.Image=Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Usr/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/randomly/randomly/Resources/dice1.jpg");
}
```

How can I make a shorter image path?

Comment: It seems like the title of your question is different than your actual question. Are you asking how to imbed a picture or how to shorten the image path?

Comment: yes actually how can i make shorter image path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed use [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx) and access it like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Resources.dice;
```

To get pictures located in the same directory where your program is running:

```
string pathToProgramDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string pathToPicture = Path.Combine(pathToProgramDirectory, "dice1.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(pathToPicture);
```

Comment: @user3060520 yes they are similar. But once you get "unexpected" path returned by `GetCurrentDirectory()` you will learn the difference. Some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727692/what-is-the-difference-between-these-ways-of-getting-current-directory). That's why I am usually using assembly location to get current directory.